# Hash method for database string search?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL InnoDB database and one of the fields in a table is `term VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL`

This is too large, as it can be 255*3 = 765 bytes. It's still within the limit of 767 bytes InnoDB has, but I want to speed up searches based on the `term` as well save space by reducing the size of the indexes.

Instead of using the `term` as a key, I decided to use a hash of `term`.

What kind of hash method should I use?

**edit:** I am storing search terms, e.g. "how to find a new car", "iphone 5", "best yugioh card" etc

Comment: No clue on what you are storing so it is hard to tell.  Easy answer is any hash (MD5?) should do the job if you are ready to manage the collisions.

Comment: @ForguesR: is it possible to be 100% sure no collisions will happen, using only 8 bytes?

Comment: No, it is not possible.  But if it happens you can compare with the clear text search term if you also keep it.

Comment: @ForguesR: It makes sense to not be possible. So, I am looking for the fastest algorithm, with as few collision as possible. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed Is it a great idea to use some unknown hash like Murmur or better go with one well know like MD5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL includes the [MD5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) algorithm. The resulting hash is only 32 hex characters, or 16 binary "bytes".

Comment: Thanks, is there any other better algorithm than MD5?

Comment: Better how? I think you would want short, fast, with good, "random" distribution, and common implementation. MD5 fits the bill. There are a few known collisions, but none of them word length or human readable.

Comment: So, I am looking for the fastest algorithm, with as few collision as possible. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed Is it a great idea to use some unknown hash like Murmur or better go with one well know like MD5?

Comment: Murmur had 6 collisions just with the list of English words. MD5 is widely implemented and plenty fast. I say, just use MD5.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use MD5 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE termtable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    term VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    termhash char(32) not null,
    primary key (id),
    key (termhash)
);
```

If you are looking for one specific value and those values could be lengths well beyond 32 characters, you could store the hash value:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (term,termhash)
VALUES ('a long string',MD5('a long string'));
```

That way, you just such for hash values to retrieve results

```
SELECT * FROM termtable WHERE termhash = MD5('a long string');
```